# Can I use wires from top module as inputs in a bind module instantiation? (SystemVerilog)

Tags: system-verilog

I have a simple module PRINTER that I want to instantiate with bind to another module BIG_DUT in one testbench BIG_TB. BIG_DUT has an instance of another module SMALL_DUT, which has most stuff that I want to use in PRINTER. I have another testbench SMALL_TB which has an instance of SMALL_DUT as well as an instance of PRINTER, and in this testbench I would like to bind the PRINTER to the SMALL_DUT.

In my PRINTER module I need a wire that is present in either testbench, as well as in BIG_DUT, **but not in SMALL_DUT**. Is there any way to use the wire from the testbench instead of trying to access the wire inside of BIG_DUT/SMALL_DUT, while still having easy access to other wires/stuff in SMALL_DUT?

Example code:

```
module SMALL_DUT();
   // Stuff I want to use in the PRINTER
   ...
endmodule


module BIG_DUT(
   input wire big_dut_input
);
   SMALL_DUT small_dut_in_big();
endmodule


module PRINTER(
   // Can I take input here from tb?
);
   // For BIG_TB, I could use big_dut_input and small_dut_in_big.stuff_i_want_to_use

   // For SMALL_TB, there is no wire I could use, but I can reference stuff_i_want_to_use
endmodule


module BIG_TB();
   wire my_tb_wire_big;  // Want to use this in PRINTER, also present in BIG_DUT

   BIG_DUT big_dut(
      .big_dut_input(my_tb_wire_big)
   );

   // I could potentially do
   // bind big_dut.small_dut_in_big
   // here to get the same access pattern to stuff inside PRINTER
   bind big_dut
   PRINTER big_printer(
      // Could I input my_tb_wire_big here?
   );
endmodule


module SMALL_TB();
   wire my_tb_wire_small;  // Same usage as my_tb_wire_big in PRINTER
   ...
   SMALL_DUT small_dut();

   bind small_dut
   PRINTER small_printer(
      // Could I input my_tb_wire_small here?
   );
endmodule
```

(In this simple example I could of course add another input to SMALL_DUT, but that is used in my real code, and I don't want the extra input there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always put a hierarchical reference in an instance port connection. This is true regardless of using the `bind` construct or not.

```
module SMALL_DUT();
  bit stuff;
   ...
endmodule

module BIG_DUT(
   input wire big_dut_input
);
   SMALL_DUT small_dut_in_big();
endmodule
module PRINTER(
   input signal1, signal2, signal3)
 // stuff
endmodule


module BIG_TB();
   wire my_tb_wire_big;  // Want to use this in PRINTER, also present in BIG_DUT

   BIG_DUT big_dut(
      .big_dut_input(my_tb_wire_big)
   );

   bind big_dut
   PRINTER big_printer(
      BIG_TB.my_tb_wire_big, small_dut_in_big.stuff);
   );
endmodule


module SMALL_TB();
   wire my_tb_wire_small;  // Same usage as my_tb_wire_big in PRINTER
   ...
   SMALL_DUT small_dut();

   bind small_dut
   PRINTER small_printer(
     SMALL_TB.my_tb_wire_small, stuff
   );
endmodule
```